# Selecting an element inside a div

Tags: html

I want to use CSS to select the div with the highest id.  In this example, it would be "respondentscolumn2" but that could change (it may be respondentscolumn3, respondentscolumn4...etc)

Thank you

```
***<div class="box generalbox">
    <div class="box generalbox py-3">...< /div>
    <div class="box generalbox">
         <div id="respondentscolumn0" class="respondentscolumn">...< /div>
         <div id="respondentscolumn1" class="respondentscolumn">...< /div>
         <div id="respondentscolumn2" class="respondentscolumn">...< /div>
         <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>  
</div>***
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
div[id^="respondentscolumn"]:last-child {
  /* Your styles here */
}
```